# Use continuationToken when creating files from a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a spreadsheet to generate a bunch of Google Docs for certificates. I know I can use a continuation token to save my iteration point when I'm looping through folders or files in Drive, but I'm having a hard time of doing the same when generating files from a Spreadsheet.

There is no UI for the script, and I'd like to stay away from creating one, if possible, so I don't want to use a server/client callback to check.

Is the best method in a bound script to do small loops (20-25 files) and then check the length of the array to continue? Is it possible to get a token when looping through a sheet rather than a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get a token, I added a simple utility function to the script to check the runtime on each loop and close properly.

```
function isTimeUp_(starttime) {
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getTime() - starttime.getTime() > 270000; // 4.5 minutes
}

function makeDocs() {
  var starttime = new Date();
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (isTimeUp_(starttime )) {
      Logger.log("Time up, finished on row " + i);
      break;
    }
    // rest of the loop if false
  }
}
```

The script runs on a time trigger set to 15 minutes. A status column is checked to start the loop in the correct location on the next trigger event.